# Overriding UITableView in Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

All,

In swift while using Parse as my backend, I have created a class which inherits from PFQueryTableViewController. I see my data going into a tableview - thats fine.

I am trying to customise my cells a bit, and I overriding CellForRowAtIndexPath - like below :

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell!

   {
    var cellIdentifier = "eventCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? PFTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {

        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    }

    // configure cell
    var CellTitle = object.objectForKey("Title") as String
    cell?.textLabel = CellTitle
   }


}
```

As the object using comes back as [AnyObject] in swift, I have created a variable and I have casted it to a string. And then I am trying to show that string in Cell.textlabel.

I am getting the error : Cannot assign to the result of this expression. 
Can anyone please show me the right direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're attempting to assign a `String` directly to `cell?.textLabel` `UILabel`. Instead try changing this line:

```
cell?.textLabel = CellTitle
```

to this

```
cell.textLabel?.text = CellTitle
```

so you're setting the text property of the `UILabel` instead.